# Positive definite matrix with positive entries

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, symmetric-matrices, positive-definite

I have a question about linear algebra.

My question is:

Is any real symmetric matrix $A$ with non-negative entries such that $\det(A)>0$ positive definite?

Thank you.

Comment: "positive entries" or "non-negative entries"?  It does not really matter, as there are counterexamples.  What have you tried?

Comment: I meant that all entries $a_{i,j}\geq 0$.
If $A$ is of size 2, then it is true.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no. For example,
$$
A = \pmatrix{1&2&2\\2&1&2\\2&2&1}
$$
is symmetric with positive entries and $\det(A) = 5 > 0$, but it has negative eigenvalue $-1$ with multiplicity $2$.